# Why am I getting a 'str' objet is not callable error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

my code:

```
import cv2 import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES=['Dog','Cat']

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE=50
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath,cv2.IMGREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x3-CNN.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('dog.jpg')]) print(prediction)
```

my error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-182101876678> in <module>
     10     return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
     11 
---> 12 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x3-CNN.model")
     13 
     14 prediction = model.predict([prepare('dog.jpg')])

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Check your saved model name with extension and put in the same directory.

Comment: It would be great if you upvote my comment. wellcome

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error while loading a saved `pb` model in TensorFlow. Turns out that I didn't save the model using Keras, so had to load the model using `tf.saved_model.load('model_directory')` instead of using Keras.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. Actually I tried to save with .keras and .h5 extensions. When I was tryin to use tf.keras.models.load_model() or tf.saved_model.load() it would give this error. Seeing Anjul Tyagi's answer inspired me to save the model just as a folder (without writing an extension in the saving path) and then loaded it again just as a folder. And it worked. So, I wrote not ("model.keras") or ("model.h5") but just ("model").

Btw I never got this error while saving and then loading models I wrote myself. This time I used hub.KerasLayer() and I think that's what caused the error. So, **bottom line**: saved and loaded the model as a folder. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

May be these are the factors to produce this error....

1. You saved the model different name.
2. You saved the model in different directory with correct name or incorrect name
3. your extension is wrong

In your case, Your extension of the model is wrong since there is no extenison like model"
Check Your extension of the model. It may "h5"
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#hdf5_format